# How to type function range such as f: Z to N

Tags: math-mode

I am new to latex and I am having trouble typing the function range before I define the function. So I am trying to define a piecewise function, and how would I have something like this?[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please always provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for your question. Assuming that you load the amssymb package, the code is `$f:\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$`, but you should really use `\to` instead of `\mapsto` here.

Comment: Hi, for some reason, it keeps giving me undefined control sequence when I use mathbb.

Comment: add  `\usepackage{amssymb}` to your preamble

Comment: I posted a code below. Please tell me when you read and understood it, I'll erase it then.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, Mico!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$ is more correct than
$f\colon\mathbb{Z}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$.
\begin{align}
 f\colon\mathbb{Z}&\to\mathbb{N}\notag\\
 n&\mapsto \left( n\mod 3\right)^2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please change all three instances of `:` to `\colon`. (The former is a relational operator.)

Comment: @Mico: Will do ... but I did not intend to keep this post.